# I don't know why my webpage won't stop loading

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, web, google-chrome-devtools, loading

I'm still a newbie when it comes to backend stuff and I have a web page that won't stop loading. How would I even troubleshoot this? I've gone into the Networking tab of Inspect Element but I'm not sure what I'm looking at or if that will help me.

If anyone has any tips on how to look for what's causing this that would be fantastic.

Comment: If the server isn't responding then there isn't much you can do from the browser.  The browser is just waiting for a response.  It has no control over the server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if a HTML DOM element has yet to fully load/appear, it will show the webpage is still loading. But, assuming you already investigated potential front-end problems, it may in fact be a PHP/JavaScript file causing the seemingly infinite loading. The question is, do you have some sort of functionality that is constantly being called in the back-end? For example, a script that's keeping track of mouse position? Session length? If you are using a third-party web host like GoDaddy or something with out-of-the-box web hosting, check your public HTML directory using your FTP service and see if you can find a PHP or JavaScript file causing this issue. However, don't forget JS can be inside an HTML doc as well, so make sure you are in control / are aware of what files your website is using.

Now, I'm sure people may jump out and slam me for saying JS/PHP can cause the front-end to appear as "loading," but take into account that these back-end technologies can indeed affect front-end; i.e. "Your session is about to expire, keep it active?" This is especially true when you add in database manipulation, like PHP to a MySQL DB.